# Reverse Geocoding in PHP request

Tags: php, google-api

I would like to Reverse Geocoding (from GPS coordinates to addresses) and I have a http request from Google Api and is :

```
 $StringaCo= file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='. $x . ', '.$y.'&sensor=false&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=AIzaSyDX7vrxKQI2cHWLS7aghb1ORv1dRX_yQSk');
```

and I process this http request with :

```
$StringL= json_decode($StringaCo);
```

now I want to print all with :

```
print_r($StringL);
```

but I received this error :

**Warning** : file_get_contents(https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=41.805931099999995, 12.432546499999999&sensor=false&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=AIzaSyDX7vrxKQI2cHWLS7aghb1ORv1dRX_yQSk): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request.

Could someone, please, help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change:

```
$StringaCo= file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$x.', '.$y.'&sensor=false&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=AIzaSyDX7vrxKQI2cHWLS7aghb1ORv1dRX_yQSk');
```

to:

```
$StringaCo= file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='. $x.','.$y.'&sensor=false&location_type=ROOFTOP&result_type=street_address&key=AIzaSyDX7vrxKQI2cHWLS7aghb1ORv1dRX_yQSk');
```

you need remove extra space after comma